# Outputting stdout or stderr in python setUpClass

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I'm writing tests using python 2.7.11 unittest module, and would like to echo some details from setup code in setUpClass to the unittest-xml-reporting log.  Is there any way to not have output to stdout and/or stderr suppressed for the xml output?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the logger but I've had to use the error method for it to print to the screen right out of the box. Ex

```
import logging

expect = ...
actual = ...
logging.error('%d, %d', expect, actual)
```

Comment: Updated the question, I realized that I forgot to mention it is in the xml log that I was hoping to avoid suppressing the output.  I've also found that the stdout is suppressed on the terminal but stderr will show when using logging.  Unfortunately I'm trying to humanize the unittest output for non-devs to understand.